# Поле #hidden в Drupal

Tags: drupal, api

Надежда только на вас.  Пишу свой модуль для Drupal 7. В `hook_menu` нужно обработать ссылку по типу "название/число".

Изучив документацию по `hook_menu` на официальном сайте (английский я знаю плохо, так что интуитивно, программирую давно на php, может что то не до конца понял). Насколько я понял, в items нужно создать по типу "название/%" либо "название/%название_переменной" .

В первом варианте получить число в "функции возврата" у меня удалось. Но я понял, что бы использовать эту переменную, например, в другом "хуке", нужно использовать `hook_load` для которой использую второй вариант, в функции `hook_load` получаю первым аргументом и выдаю ее return. И когда мне нужно будет обратиться к переменной я могу вызвать `название_переменной_load()`... Но увы, не получается. Мне это нужно что бы в `hook_form` в поле типа `hidden` в значение поместить число из ссылки... Help!

Comment: говорили мне, учи английский...

Comment: После изменения hook_menu нужно отключить и включить модуль? когда этот хук выполняется?

Comment: я щас уже hool_destroy в своем мозге запущу! HELP

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать arg(1) в данном случае.

Answer (score 0):

В функции возврата в drupal_get_form() вторым аргументом передать переменную и в hook_form третим аргументом получить использовать эту переменную.